# How to handle an System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when the last month is reached

Tags: c#

The following code section is used to output the date. I always need the following month. However, a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown from this code:

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month+1, 1);
```

When `startTime` has reached the 12th month. As I understand it, the year is not increased by +1, which ultimately leads to this exception. I've tried to catch the exception but with no success. How can I handle this exception and take the year into account?

```
        public static List<string> GetMonthDays()
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month+1, 1);
            int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(startTime.Year, startTime.Month);
            List<string> currentMonth = new List<string>();
            //string[] currentMonth = new string[daysInMonth];
            for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; ++i)
            {
                DateTime currentDate = startOfMonth.AddDays(i);
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                currentMonth.Add(currentDate.ToString("dddd - dd.MM.yy", ci));
            }
            return currentMonth;

        }
```

Comment: Why would the year change in this method? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Note that the code in the question will **NOT** throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException (hence my downvote). Proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Wb3aQ

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I was a little vague with my statement. It throws an exception if I try to increase the month by +4, in order to simulate the month of January of the next year. ` DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month+4, 1);` With ` DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month+3, 1);` it works.

Comment: Your question is entirely different from what you just said in your comment. That's not a little vague, your question is is simply misleading, as it does not represent the actual logic/code you are having a problem with. And you made a false claim, because you based your claim not on the code in the question, but on some other code logic that's not part of your question...

Comment: @DavidG My idea was as follows: If I increase the month by +1 (so that I have the following month), the year will automatically change when I reach the month of December. However, this is not the case.

Comment: If you have code that doesn't work, then *show us that code*. Giving us the code that works is super unhelpful. Also, I assume you want to create your `startTime` value, so add months to that?

Comment: Also, `DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month+3, 1);` does not work either. Or in other words, that works just as fine as `DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month+4, 1);` Can you imagine a scenario where `new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month+3, 1);` fails just like it would with `new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month+4, 1)`?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I have edited the code to match my statement.

Comment: Why not use `new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)`? The DateTime constructor month parameter expects a value month value (1-12). You'd be passing it 13 in the way you do it right now. Which is why it is argument out of range.

Comment: To always get January of the following year you could do var january = startTime.AddMonths((12 - d.Month) + 1);

Comment: @DavidG I did, and it was not my intention to mislead you guys.

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax `new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)` is the solution for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Marco glad we got there in the end :) I'll add an answer for you to approve.

Comment: @Marco I've added an answer for you to accept, so we can close the question down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following code ...

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month+1, 1);
```

To ...

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 1).AddMonths(1)
```